# Whenever I execute the cursor.execute statement, it's only returning integer as an output?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymysql

I had connected my MySQL database with PyMySQL as a connector, and it executed perfectly, but whenever I try to execute or run `cursor.execute("some statement ")`, it's returning only an integer value as an output.

**Code:**

```
import pymysql
db=  
pymysql.connect(host='localhost',port=3306,user='root',passwd='')
c = db.cursor()
c.execute("show databases;")
c.execute("use tracer;") #my database name
c.execute("select * from stud;")
```

**Output:**

`c.execute("show databases;")`

I expected the output as a name of some databases but it provided only `7` as output.

`c.execute("select * from stud;")`

I expected the output as data in tuples but the output I received was
`3`, i.e, number of rows.

Comment: An `int` is precisely what `.execute()` is documented to return.  You then use `.fetchone()`, `.fetchmany()`, or `.fetchall()` to actually retrieve the rows.

Comment: thanks @jasonharper

Answer (score 1):

```
cursor.execute(sqlite_select_query)
records = cursor.fetchall()
```

the records will now hold the row data as a list of tuples
https://pynative.com/python-cursor-fetchall-fetchmany-fetchone-to-read-rows-from-table/

Comment: @jasonharper, this post was left for 3 years without an answer. I think you can edit this answer also reflect your comment on the original post if you have time